# android animation on orientation change

Tags: android, animation, orientation

I have to give an animation effect when i change the orientation of screen from Portrait to landscape and vice versa. How can i go about doing this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to animate? Transition between screens portrait/landscape or you have some other animation not related to the layout? Btw. Deva is my nickname :)

Comment: Hi Zelimir, I am looking for slide (Bottom to top) effect when i move from Portrait/landscape and vice versa. I have a seperate xml defined for the same.

Comment: So, when screen rotation happens new screen arises from the Bottom until it is completely displayed? What elements does your screen contain?

Comment: yes the new screen appears from the bottom. My screen contains a canvas containing a graph.

Answer (score -1):

use overridePendingTransition (int enterAnim, int exitAnim) in your onCreate() method of activity.
and your activity should not having android:configChanges="orientation" tag in manifest, otherwise oncreate will not be called on orientation change...hope this will help you...what i got from you

Comment: Sam as per my understanding overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim , int exitAnim) can only be used after startActivity(Intent) or finish() [ correct me if wrong ] so how do i use it in case of an orientation change and not a new activity start.

Comment: yes you are right here...but as i remember i had also used it in onCreate() method just after super call, and it also works there... i think you should make a try

Comment: One more thing. This is used to start some ready animation from resources, I think he wants to animate layout transition.